# Ввод текста в Yasm

Tags: ассемблер, ос, yasm

Надо сделать такое как например ввел на ассемблере единицу,в коде указано что 1 = Завершение работы а 2 = Перезагрузка.Если число больше чем 1 или 2 то нужно вывести то что ввёл пользователь.Покажите пример как реализовать такое. Так как я пытался,но ничего не получается.Либо он на любую клавишу завершение/перезагрузку.Код

```
section .text
use16
org 0x7c00
%include 'Graphics.asm' 
start:
section .data

mov ah,0

int 16h
mov ah, 0x0e
int 10h

int 16h
cmp ah,1

mov ax, 5307h
xor bx, bx
inc bx
mov cx, 3
int 15h

int 16h
cmp ah,2

int 19h

jmp $
```

Comment: Я добавил уже проблему.Могу скинуть код если хотите

Comment: Код надо было прикладывать сразу, чтобы вам объяснили, что вы сделали не так.

Comment: Добавил код.Код небольшой.

Comment: Почему Вы вызываете 0x16 прерывание сразу после вывода `AL`? У Вас в `AH` остаётся 0x0e, у 0x16 прерывания не предусмотрен аргумент `AH = 0x0E`. Далее, Вы после ввода сравниваете `AH` с 1, что неправильно. `INT 0x10, AH=0x00` возвращает в `AL` ASCII код символа (для 1 это 0x31), а в `AH` сканкод клавиши (для 1 это 0x02). Для 2 те же значения +1. Дальше сами, отталкиваясь от этого. Будут вопросы - спрашивайте.

Comment: Я делал по гайду.Но думаю то что сам уже дальше справлюсь

Comment: Я надеюсь, Вы не бездумно копировали код? Прерывания BIOS можно посмотреть [тут](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/int.htm). Сканкоды клавиш [тут](https://wiki.osdev.org/PS/2_Keyboard).